# skip columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, baselineremoval

I have a dataframe with many columns and I used the following code to convert each column into a list. Then I need to check if the first value in each list equals 0, if yes, then skip this list and not running the following function (baseline removal function in my case). But I still want to keep this list in my final dataframe. I tried to used the `if...continue` function, it can skip this list but cannot keep this original list. Is there any way to achieve that?

```
Master=[]

for i in df.columns:
temp = df[i].values.tolist()
if temp [0] == 0:
    continue
baseObj=BaselineRemoval(temp)
Zhangfit_output=baseObj.ZhangFit()
Master.append(Zhangfit_output)

output = pd.DataFrame (Master)
```

Comment: can you add your input dataframe and expected output please? please see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` function first and then `continue` function

```
Master=[]
for i in df.columns:
temp = df[i].values.tolist()
if temp [0] == 0:
    Master.append(temp)   
else:
    baseObj=BaselineRemoval(temp)
    Zhangfit_output=baseObj.ZhangFit()
    Master.append(Zhangfit_output)


output = pd.DataFrame (Master)
```